# Prototype: find all elements with a certain class?

Tags: prototypejs

Using the Prototype js framework, how do you find all elements with a certain class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [the $$ function](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar-dollar/) to get elements by class:

```
$$(".myclass")
```

Will give you an array of elements you can iterate over. This function allows you to use any css selector to get the elements, too:

```
$$("li.myclass")
$$("p#test")
```

Comment: For any who come across this in the future: it looks like this function is available in PrototypeJS 1.5+.  If I'm wrong about this, someone please correct me.

Answer (score 4):

http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar-dollar

$$ lets you pass in any css selector.

```
$$('.class')
```